# Sort array of hashes by property AND exact match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

Let's say I've got the following array of hashes:

```
arr = [{:name=>"foo", :value=>20},
       {:name=>"bar", :value=>25}, 
       {:name=>"baz", :value=>30}]
```

I'm currently sorting by `value` like so:

```
arr.sort{|a,b| b[:value] <=> a[:value] }
```

Is it possible to move an element (i.e. the one in which `name == 'bar'`) to the top of the stack *after* sorting without chaining another method? Ideally, this would just be some more  in the sort block.

Comment: Note that this sort is the canonical example of why `sort_by` was created: `arr.sort_by { |h| h[:value] }`.

Answer (score 2):

fast solution (can be refactored, I think)

```
arr.sort{|a,b| a[:name] == 'bar' ? -1 : b[:name] == 'bar' ? 1 : b[:value] <=> a[:value] }
# => [{:name=>"bar", :value=>25}, {:name=>"baz", :value=>30}, {:name=>"foo", :value=>20}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use a less verbose (and more efficient) [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) with [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
arr.sort_by { |h| -h[:value]] }
```

Now, taking advantage of the [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) defined by arrays, what you asked for may be written:

```
arr.sort_by { |h| [h[:name] == "bar" ? 0 : 1, -h[:value]] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.sort do |a,b|
  if a[:name] == "bar" && b[:name] != "bar"
    # a is bar but b is not, put a to the top, i.e. a is smaller than b
    -1
  elsif a[:name] != "bar" && b[:name] == "bar"
    # a is not bar but b is, put b to the top, i.e. a is bigger than b
    1
  else
    # both a and b are "bar", or bot are not "bar", than we can sort them normally
    a[:value] <=> b[:value]
  end
end
```

a dirty solution, thinking how to write better...